# Is there any way I can avoid Turtle slowing down the more lines it has to print?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I made a program to generate a random 2D array of 1s and 0s that I then print as green "land" tiles above a blue background to generate a little 'map'. I've tried to optimise the code as much as I know how but when I try to print anything above 100x100, it slows down by a LOT. If I set it to print line by line, I see that it's taking quite a lot longer to print lines the more of the map turtle has already printed. I don't know why this is (I don't know much about turtle or rendering in general) but I would quite like to know how to solve this problem.
If this is not possible, could I have recommendations for other libraries/languages that I could try this in? I'd like to do more programs like this and I don't mind learning something new. :)

Here is my code:

```
import turtle
import random
import time

d = turtle.Turtle()
d.ht()
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setup(width=0.45,height=0.8,startx=800,starty=50)
wn.bgcolor("#002240")
turtle.tracer(0,0)
d.penup()
interval = 10

def square(col) :
    d.pendown()
    d.color(col)
    d.begin_fill()
    for i in range(4) :
        d.fd(interval)
        d.right(90)
    d.end_fill()
    d.penup()

size = int(input("Enter map size  "))
custom_interval = input("Custom interval?  ")
if custom_interval != '' :
    interval = int(custom_interval)
int_by_size = interval * size

start_gen = time.time()
data = []
for i in range(size) :
    gen_line = []
    [gen_line.append(random.randint(0,1)) for i in range(size)]
    data.append(gen_line)
end_gen = time.time()
print("GEN DONE IN",end_gen-start_gen)

d.goto(-int_by_size/2,int_by_size/2)
start_draw = time.time()

d.pendown()
d.color("blue")
d.begin_fill()
for i in range(4) :
    d.fd(int_by_size)
    d.right(90)
d.end_fill()
d.penup()

for y,line in enumerate(data) :

    for x,tile in enumerate(line) :

        if tile == 1 :
            square("green")
            d.fd(interval)
        else :
            d.fd(interval)

    #Comment out to print entire map at once
    turtle.update()
        
    d.backward(int_by_size)
    d.sety(d.ycor()-interval)
    
end_draw = time.time()
print("DRAW DONE IN",end_draw-start_draw)
           
wn.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My rework of your code below speeds up the drawing by an order of magnitude by switching from *drawing* to *stamping* and other tricks:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint
import time

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

interval = 10

size = int(input("Enter map size: "))
custom_interval = input("Custom interval: ")
if custom_interval != '':
    interval = int(custom_interval)
int_by_size = interval * size

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=0.45, height=0.8, startx=800, starty=50)
screen.bgcolor('#002240')
screen.tracer(False)

x, y = interval/2 - int_by_size/2, int_by_size/2 - interval/2

start_gen = time.time()

data = [(randint(False, True) for _ in range(size)) for _ in range(size)]

print("GEN DONE IN", time.time() - start_gen)

start_draw = time.time()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.shape('square')
turtle.penup()

turtle.color('blue')
turtle.shapesize(int_by_size / CURSOR_SIZE)
turtle.stamp()

turtle.color('green')
turtle.shapesize(interval / CURSOR_SIZE)
turtle.goto(x, y)

for line in data:
    dx = x

    for tile in line:
        if tile:
            turtle.setx(dx)
            turtle.stamp()

        dx += interval

    # Comment out to print entire map at once
    screen.update()

    y -= interval
    turtle.goto(x, y)

print("DRAW DONE IN", time.time() - start_draw)

screen.tracer(True)
screen.exitonclick()
```

Some of my optimizations you may need to undo, like making the data a list of generators instead of a list of lists (speeds up data generation but is only good for a single pass.)  Also, remember that a window size of `width=0.45, height=0.8` is relative to the size of *your* screen -- other folks running on other screens will get a different size window.